# Best performance HTTP library in Python

Tags: python, http

As the title says, I'm looking for information about the best library to send HTTP requests in Python really fast.

Do you know which one is the fastest and/or consume less CPU time/memory ?

- urllib2
- httplib2
- requests

Thanks

Comment: As Eric Lippert put it so nicely, "If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses." http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 3):

You should not waste your time on finding a fast HTTP library, instead, you should think about architecture and the big picture.

Here I list some directions

1. Use async network library, such as [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/), [Gevent](http://www.gevent.org/), [Tulip](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/), to send request in async manner
2. Use [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module of Python, to distribute work loading to different processors
3. Use [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/%E2%80%8E), to distribute work loading to different nodes

By finding a better HTTP library might only gain you 5% ~ 20% performance boost, but by doing it with proper approach, you can do it really fast from over all view. You can also combine all these manners mentioned above.

Another performance issue about getting information from Internet, especially HTTP, it is actually slower to parse HTML than sending requests. [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is your best friend if you want to parse HTML/XML and fetch data from it really fast. You can read this [article about HTML parser performance](http://www.ianbicking.org/blog/2008/03/python-html-parser-performance.html).

Answer (score 2):

urllib2 might be better for performance, but requests is much simpler to use.

Answer (score 0):

Sending HTTP request is pretty simple, I don't think it could be a block issue for most  real world applications.

If you really want to send request very fast, you can consider to use multi processes, not waste your time on choosing a faster library(Which likely to be helpless).